# How to get the highest value from MySQL column

Tags: php, mysql

I actually want to get the highest value from my MySQL database column and I tried the mentioned code but as per the record highest value is **10200**    but  the query is showing **9999** as the highest value .. Kindly help me how to get the highest value

MYSQLI QUERY & PHP

```
$tquery = 'SELECT MAX(bill_no) AS lastbill FROM msr_bills';
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con,$tquery));
$nextbillno = $row['lastbill'];
```

Comment: What is the data type of `bill_no` - is it sorting it as a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the column `bill_no` is defined as a character column such as `CHAR` or `VARCHAR` then MySql is doing a character rather than numeric comparison and you need to first convert your column to a numeric:

`$tquery = 'SELECT MAX(CAST(bill_no as UNSIGNED)) AS lastbill FROM msr_bills';`

You might consider for the future converting the column to a numeric type with enough precision to hold the largest bill number you will have and then you will not have to use the CAST function.

Comment: I changed Character Column  to VARCHAR .. its working perfect now

Comment: @user3694260 But you will still have to continue to perform call to CAST to convert it a numeric if you wish to get the MAX value. If you changed it to, for example, INT (can handle bill numbers up to 8 digits, BIGINT(up to 18 digits) or DECIMAL(N) where N is the number of digits in a bill number, for example DECIMAL(10), then you would just need `$tquery = 'SELECT MAX(bill_no) AS lastbill from msr_bills';`

Comment: Ok .. I got It!

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
SELECT bill_no as lastbill  FROM msr_bills ORDER BY bill_no DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: This will work only if autoincrement was used.